# How RAM is too much?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ram

I am building an app and currently it has around 12 screens. Upon completion I am estimating around 20. Recently I read a question regarding max RAM was a problem. Is maxing out a users iPhones RAM actually a possibility? If so what do I do to control it?

Comment: Yes. What to do? Don't use too much of it. But unless you actually have a problem and horrible design, you won't easily have a problem.

Comment: It depends on what exactly you're doing, but 20 screens isn't that bad nowadays on modern devices.

Comment: There are many, many WWDC sessions on controlling application memory use. I suggest reviewing the last 2 years of WWDC sessions.